# Need an advice about SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm writing you because I need some advice.

I'm working on SSRS reports and SQL Server 2012 during my internship for an enterprise. I wrote reports with interaction parameters, but some reports are very slow when someone wants to use/run them on SQL Server Reporting Services. As the enterprise uses Windows integrated security, I can't configure cached reports in order to improve execution time for reports with main (or default) parameters.

At the end, my goal is: if people who need to see reports can receive an email every Sunday for example, with a link for new reports... That could be awesome.

Could someone give me an advice please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule Reports on SSRS and send them in Excel format with default parameters. Just click on manage on the report and select subscriptions.
You can even select the emails from a query.
Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762(v=sql.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But I don't know if the solution can help me.
First I can't configure a subscription. I have the issue: "Subscription cannot be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored". It's the same issue with cached reports. 
And if I send an email contents reports with Excel format, people couldn't change parameters if they want. No ?

Comment: @MiniMonster What do you think is missing?

Comment: Sry, I modified the previous comment for more precisions

Comment: @MiniMonster Yes, scheduled reports must be executed with the same user with stored credentials. When we send excel format it's usually with not many filters, since the user can filter the data in excel. If the reports are slow, you should check your queries and see if there is a way to optimize it. You could also save the results of the query in a table every night and query that table from SSRS

Comment: Well, I will try. Thank you very much for your answers :)
+1